# Export an Excel Chart as a TIF using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to export Excel 365 charts in bulk as TIFs using VBA. The code works when I export PNGs but, when creating TIFs, it exports empty image files.

Simplified code:

```vb
'Save the charts
MyFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Chart.tif"
Worksheets("Charts").ChartObjects(1).Chart.Export _
Filename:=MyFileName, FilterName:="TIF"
```

When the references to TIF are changed to PNG, this works as expected.

Why TIF? The intent is for these to be printed, so they need the resolution. I have achieved this in R but I was asked to make it in Excel as well.

I know Excel 365 can save charts in TIF format (select chart, right click, Save as Picture..., save as type has the option for .tif).

I tried swapping references of TIF to TIFF, in the event the filter is inconsistent. I also tried to find a list of the valid FilterName options.

Comment: I'm guessing this is not possible. Someone asked an almost identical question a few days ago, except SVG instead of TIF. I don't think either format works in `Chart.Export`.

Comment: You can see your available filters here: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Graphics Filters\Export

Comment: That's unfortunate and a little confusing. They've built the functionality, would be nice to them to let it be called by VBA.

Comment: Eh VBA doesn't get enough love from MSFT.

Comment: @TimWilliams My registry has no such directory. Did a search for Graphics Filters and didn't find any instance of it (Win 10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I HATE this but it works.

```
Sub Test()
Dim Filename As String
Filename = "State_Chart.tif"
Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
Application.SendKeys ("+{F10}")
Application.SendKeys ("S")
Application.SendKeys ("S")
Application.SendKeys ("{RETURN}")
Application.SendKeys (Filename)
Application.SendKeys ("{TAB}")
Application.SendKeys ("T")
Application.SendKeys ("{RETURN}")
End Sub
```

This selects the charts and then sends the keyboard keys to open the menu, select save as picture, enter a file name, select tiff (use S for SVG), and press enter to close the dialogue box.